# Form with lots of controls with interaction between them. Cleaner approach than $scope.$watch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an angular app and the form has about 15 controls. It’s a finance application. Please don’t suggest to break down the page etc.

Some of the controls depend on each other. There are about 5 input controls (lets call them source controls), any of which can change, and impact one or more of 5 other controls (lets call them dest controls). The way I have it structured is that I have a $scope.$watch on each of the 5 source variables and in each watch function I have some code to decide which of the 5 dest variables are to be updated and I update them. Example of one of the watches is shows below.

```
$scope.$watch('money.price',function(newVal,oldVal) {

    if(newVal != oldVal) {

        if($scope.money.quantity != undefined) {
            updatePrincipal($scope)
            updateFees($scope);
            $scope.money.net = $scope.money.principal + $scope.money.fee 
        }
    }
});
```

I don’t really find this elegant. Is there a better / cleaner way to do this ? (The form will only get a little more complex in the future i.e. 2-3 more dependency fields but not more than that).

Comment: So what is the problem or question? With no code provided not sure what you expect for feedback

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input controls have an ng-model attached to them, I would recommend adding ng-change to each input form, where you can probably use the same function to update all of the scope bindings at once

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the $watch that gets created with `ng-bind` directive.

```
<div ng-bind="getMoneyNet()"></div>

     OR SIMPLY

{{ getMoneyNet() }}
```

Instead of creating a $watch in your controller, define the function.

```
 $scope.getMoneyNet = function() {
     if ($scope.money.quantity != undefined) {
        updatePrincipal($scope)
        updateFees($scope);
        $scope.money.net = $scope.money.principal + $scope.money.fee 
     };
     return $scope.money.net;
 };
```

Then on each digest cycle, the `$watch` created by the `ng-bind` directive computes the value of `money.net` and updates the DOM as necessary.

Comment: This is a fantastic solution. Then what is the use of $scope.$watch anymore if one can do this ?

Comment: Indeed. `$watch` and DOM manipulation should only be done inside directives. Anywhere else is a code smell.